# How can I do viper search incrementally using / and ? in emacs?

Tags: emacs, viper-mode

something like what has been mentioned in the TODO section below:

http://common-lisp.net/project/vial/darcs/extended-viper/vimlike.el

Anyone ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the straight forward answer seems to be:

```
(define-key viper-vi-global-user-map (kbd "/") 'viper-isearch-forward)
```

Note: as a non viper user, I don't know if that defines <kbd>/</kbd> where you were expecting it to be.  Before this setting, <kbd>/</kbd> was bound to `'viper-exec-mapped-kbd-macro` - so that's what was replaced.

This answer seems too simple to be what you'd expect, as it takes about as long to type in as the message in the TODO section took.